# Adding numbers in C# for total

Tags: c#

i have a program where i am calculating the total of a meal including the tax and tip. 
My tax and tip variables are working but my total is not doing the right thing.

I have this so far:

```
String total = mealCost + tax + tip;
Console.Write ("Total: " + total);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are `mealCost`, `tax` and `tip` numeric values?

Comment: And what is "not the right thing"? You are probably getting an error message - read it and do what is says.

Comment: Why would you use a String for calculations?

Comment: You might want to use a numerical type instead of a string.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `mealCost`, `tax` and `tip` represent monetary values, you could use decimals to perform arithmetic.

```
decimal mealCost = 125.99M; // expensive restaurant
decimal tax = 14.99M;
decimal tip = mealCost*.16M;

decimal total = mealCost + tax + tip;
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0:C}", total);
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to change `string` to `var` and "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'" will disappear (because `var` will pick correct numeric type):

```
var total = mealCost + tax + tip;
Console.Write ("Total: " + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you are trying to put a number in a string. Why not try a numeric type? Also make sure that mealCost, Tax, and tip are also numeric variables and not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change total to an int or double, you cant do math calculations on a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option for what you could do:

```
/* These values are just examples. */
decimal mealCost = 9.99M;
decimal tip = 2.00M;
decimal tax = 0.75M;

/* And then you can add comfortably */
decimal total = mealCost + tip + tax;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total: {0}", total));
```

Answer (score 0):

If "mealCost", "tax", "tip" are numeric values try this:

```
decimal total = mealCost + tax + tip;
Console.Write ("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: +0: `int` for money is only acceptable for really reach people... regular folks usually stick with `decimal` for food.